# Laravel Block Https Request

Tags: laravel, https

I'm developing laravel project, let's say www.domain.net

but when i try to enter https://www.domain.net

it's show the directory list with my server info (like Apache)

how to block access to https?

Answer (score 0):

your httpd.conf should look something like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin john@email.com
        #DirectoryIndex index.php
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/project"
        ServerName www.abc.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
        SSLCertificateFile /path/certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/certificate.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /path/keychain.crt
        ServerAlias abc.in
        ErrorLog logs/abc.in-error_log
        CustomLog logs/abc.in-access_log common

        <Directory "/var/www/html/project">
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```